# No Locations in MapLocationFinderResult

Tags: vb.net, geocoding

I was testing the example by microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/geocoding

This code should give me a simple output (result = (47.6406099647284,-122.129339994863))
However I get an out of range exception on `result.Locations(0)`. So I dont get any locations in my result.

```
    Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim addressToGeocode As String = "Microsoft"

        Dim queryHint As New BasicGeoposition With {.Latitude = 47.643, .Longitude = -122.131}
        Dim hintPoint As New Geopoint(queryHint)

        Dim result As MapLocationFinderResult = Await MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAsync(addressToGeocode, hintPoint, 3)

        If result.Status = MapLocationFinderStatus.Success Then
            Dim test = result.Locations(0)
            Label1.Text = $"result = ({result.Locations(0).Point.Position.Latitude},{result.Locations(0).Point.Position.Longitude})"
        End If
    End Sub
```

If I try to debug native code I get an error "MapGeocoder.pdb could not be loaded". I dont know if this causes the same trouble with the locations.

Comment: Did you incorporate maps authentication key into your app?

Comment: yes in the initialization of the form. I get a MapLocationFinderStatus.Success in the result.status, otherwise this status is invalidcredentials

Comment: Maybe include a check to ensure the are location elements in the result.  What happens if you do _Dim test = result.Locations.FirstOrDefault()_?